# Let $f(x) = \ln(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)\space$ for every $x\in{R}.\space$ then $f$ is well defined and odd.

Tags: calculus

I need to prove or disprove this statement :

Let $f(x) = \ln(\sqrt{1+x^2}-x)\space$ for every $x\in{R}.\space$ then $f$ is well defined and ood.

I need to say that this is my first time working with $\ln()$ functions so sorry if I got some misunderstandings :)

It's easy to see that the function is not odd since for:

$x=1, f(1) = e^{\sqrt{2}-1} = \frac{e^{\sqrt{2}}}{e}$

$x=-1, f(-1) = e^{\sqrt{2}+1} = {e^{\sqrt{2}}}{e}$

So $f(-x)\neq -f(x)$

but I'm not sure about "well defined". I don't see why the function is not well defined since for every $x\in R$ it's valid.

I would love to hear your thoughts!.

Comment: $\sqrt {1+x^{2}} >x$ for all $x$ so $f$ is well defined.

Comment: Note that $f(1) = \ln(\sqrt{2}-1)$ not $e^{\sqrt{2}-1}$. Also, $f(-1) = \ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$ not $e^{\sqrt{2}+1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is no doubt well-defined for all real $x$ since $\sqrt{x^2+1}>x$ holds for all real $x$. It *is* odd too, since
$$f(-x)=\ln(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)=\ln\frac{(x^2+1)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}=\ln\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}$$
$$=-\ln(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)=-f(x)$$
In fact $f(x)=-\sinh^{-1}x$.

Comment: thank you so much! as I said, this is my first time working with ln function so I clearly don't understand it enough. I need to practice more.